# Xcode - Changed enum declaration now Xcode can not find the enum types

Tags: xcode, enums

So I decided to change enum declarations. Before my declaration was defined like this in Enums.h:

```
typedef enum { 

    DateNoneReminderRepeat = 0,
    DateDayReminderRepeat = 1,
    DateWeekReminderRepeat = 2,
    DateMonthReminderRepeat = 3,
    DateYearReminderRepeat = 4

} ReminderDateRepeat;
```

Then I decided to change it to this:

```
typedef enum { 

    APDateNoneReminderRepeat = 0,
    APDateDayReminderRepeat = 1,
    APDateWeekReminderRepeat = 2,
    APDateMonthReminderRepeat = 3,
    APDateYearReminderRepeat = 4

} APReminderDateRepeat;
```

Now Xcode won't build complaining about "Parse Issue Expected a type" (see below image).

[image][Image Link As Display is small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldd8P.png)

I have cleaned the project several times to no avail.

I import the enums in my Prefix.pch file this:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
    #warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
    #import <SSToolkit/SSToolkit.h>
    #import "Enums.h"
    #import "Constants.h"
    #import "Utilities.h"

#endif
```

Comment: Image is too small to view.Can you make a change?

Comment: @Luke that does not cause an error. It worked when it was defined like that before.

Comment: @Sreeram copy the image URL and open it in a new tab.

Comment: Image shows an error on APReminderRepeatDate not APMessageType.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Fixed that now, I have more than one enum so the one in my example was not the one in the image but I have edited it now to reflect my code in this post.

Comment: @Luke nope that's perfectly valid C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. It turned out that changing the enums made Xcode go bazonkas. So it was a matter of commenting out some code to make Xcode calm down and then renaming my enum types to the changed enum types.

Answer (score 0):

You used the `ReminderDateRepeat` type throughout your code, and now this type is gone, as you have changed it to `APReminderDateRepeat`. You have two options now:

1. You have to change every occurrence of ReminderDateRepeat into APReminderDateRepeat
2. `typedef APReminderDateRepeat ReminderDateRepeat;`

Comment: I went with option 1 but I'm still getting the error as you can see from the image. Xcode does not find the enum anymore for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with derived data. So follow these steps:

1. GoTo Organizer.
2. Select location.
3. Open derived data.
4. Delete derived data.
5. Clean project.
6. Quit XCode.
7. Again Delete derived data.
8. Open XCode.
9. Clean project.
10. Build project.
11. Now these error will removed.